# Xamarin MVMM ListView not binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load a simple Collection of items into a ListView in my Xamarin Forms application. The ListView is defined in the .xaml with a Binding to `Items`.
The ViewModel uses a command to `LoadItems` which should update the contents of the List when `OnPropertyChanged` is called.

I can't figure out where this is going wrong?

The `Debug.WriteLine()` is called so I know the command is running

Thanks,

ListPage.xaml

```
  <ListView  x:Name="MyList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>           
                                   <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

ListPage.cs

```
public ListPageViewModel()
        {
            Title = "List Page";

            Task.Run(async () => await LoadItems());
        
        }

public ObservableCollection<Item> Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

public async Task LoadItems()
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("commanded to load items");
            var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); 
    
            items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
            {
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second item", Description="This is an item description." },
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First item", Description="This is an item description." }

            };

            Items = items;   

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items)); 

                
        }
```

Item.cs

```
  public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Items` must be a public **property**

Comment: As said by Jason, ```public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }```. Or just create a new project with a template, you'll find the trick.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Jason and Shaw you were correct `public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }` solved this. Thanks

Comment: @user1202278 Glad have solved that! Remember to share it in answer when you have time.